# CentOS 5 - yum update dependency error

Tags: php, centos5, repository, dependencies

I'm trying to run an update on my CentOS VPS. Ultimately what I am try to do is upgrade php53 to php55. However I appear to run in to some dependency issues. Please find below commands and outputs. I have tried to include as much information as possible. Any feedback would be appreciated. (Also running Plesk 11, but I do not think this should matter).

**yum list installed php***

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, replace, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * atomic: www7.atomicorp.com
 * webtatic-el5: nl.repo.webtatic.com
Installed Packages
php5-ioncube-loader.x86_64               4.2.2-13031415                installed
php53.x86_64                             5.3.3-22.el5_10               installed
php53-cli.x86_64                         5.3.3-22.el5_10               installed
php53-common.x86_64                      5.3.3-22.el5_10               installed
php53-gd.x86_64                          5.3.3-22.el5_10               installed
php53-imap.x86_64                        5.3.3-22.el5_10               installed
php53-mbstring.x86_64                    5.3.3-22.el5_10               installed
php53-mysql.x86_64                       5.3.3-22.el5_10               installed
php53-pdo.x86_64                         5.3.3-22.el5_10               installed
php53-xml.x86_64                         5.3.3-22.el5_10               installed
```

**rpm -q centos-release**

```
centos-release-5-10.el5.centos
```

**rpm -qa | grep 'php53-'**

```
php53-mysql-5.3.3-22.el5_10
php53-cli-5.3.3-22.el5_10
php53-gd-5.3.3-22.el5_10
php53-imap-5.3.3-22.el5_10
php53-pdo-5.3.3-22.el5_10
php53-xml-5.3.3-22.el5_10
php53-5.3.3-22.el5_10
php53-common-5.3.3-22.el5_10
php53-mbstring-5.3.3-22.el5_10
```

**yum repolist**

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, replace, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * atomic: www7.atomicorp.com
 * epel: mirror.bytemark.co.uk
 * webtatic-el5: nl.repo.webtatic.com
repo id      repo name                                                    status
atomic       CentOS / Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5 - atomicrocketturtle.com 1,499
epel         Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 5 - x86_64               7,694
webtatic-el5 Webtatic Repository EL5 - x86_64                               191
repolist: 9,384
```

**yum update**

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, replace, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * atomic: www7.atomicorp.com
 * epel: mirror.bytemark.co.uk
 * webtatic-el5: nl.repo.webtatic.com
Skipping security plugin, no data
Setting up Update Process
Resolving Dependencies
Skipping security plugin, no data
--> Running transaction check
---> Package bash-completion.noarch 1:1.3-7.el5 set to be updated
---> Package perl-Text-Iconv.x86_64 0:1.4-5.el5 set to be updated
---> Package php.x86_64 0:5.4.28-34.el5.art set to be updated
---> Package php-cli.x86_64 0:5.4.28-34.el5.art set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libedit.so.0()(64bit) for package: php-cli
---> Package php-common.x86_64 0:5.4.28-34.el5.art set to be updated
---> Package php-gd.x86_64 0:5.4.28-34.el5.art set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libt1.so.5()(64bit) for package: php-gd
---> Package php-imap.x86_64 0:5.4.28-34.el5.art set to be updated
---> Package php-ioncube-loader.x86_64 1:4.4.1-3.el5.art set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: php-devel for package: php-ioncube-loader
---> Package php-mbstring.x86_64 0:5.4.28-34.el5.art set to be updated
---> Package php-mysql.x86_64 0:5.4.28-34.el5.art set to be updated
---> Package php-pdo.x86_64 0:5.4.28-34.el5.art set to be updated
---> Package php-xml.x86_64 0:5.4.28-34.el5.art set to be updated
---> Package python26.x86_64 0:2.6.8-2.el5 set to be updated
---> Package python26-libs.x86_64 0:2.6.8-2.el5 set to be updated
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libedit.x86_64 0:3.0-2.20090923cvs.el5.art set to be updated
---> Package php-devel.x86_64 0:5.4.28-34.el5.art set to be updated
---> Package t1lib.x86_64 0:5.1.2-2.el5.art set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libXaw.so.7()(64bit) for package: t1lib
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
t1lib-5.1.2-2.el5.art.x86_64 from atomic has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: libXaw.so.7()(64bit) is needed by package t1lib-5.1.2-2.el5.art.x86_64 (atomic)
Error: Missing Dependency: libXaw.so.7()(64bit) is needed by package t1lib-5.1.2-2.el5.art.x86_64 (atomic)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: package-cleanup --problems
                        package-cleanup --dupes
                        rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
The program package-cleanup is found in the yum-utils package.
```

**yum update php**

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, replace, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * atomic: www7.atomicorp.com
 * epel: mirror.bytemark.co.uk
 * webtatic-el5: nl.repo.webtatic.com
Skipping security plugin, no data
Setting up Update Process
Resolving Dependencies
Skipping security plugin, no data
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php.x86_64 0:5.4.28-34.el5.art set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: php-common = 5.4.28-34.el5.art for package: php
--> Processing Dependency: php-cli = 5.4.28-34.el5.art for package: php
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-cli.x86_64 0:5.4.28-34.el5.art set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libedit.so.0()(64bit) for package: php-cli
---> Package php-common.x86_64 0:5.4.28-34.el5.art set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: php53-common = 5.3.3-22.el5_10 for package: php53-mbstring
--> Processing Dependency: php53-common = 5.3.3-22.el5_10 for package: php53-gd
--> Processing Dependency: php53-common = 5.3.3-22.el5_10 for package: php53-pdo
--> Processing Dependency: php53-common = 5.3.3-22.el5_10 for package: php53-xml
--> Processing Dependency: php53-common = 5.3.3-22.el5_10 for package: php53-imap
--> Processing Dependency: php53-common = 5.3.3-22.el5_10 for package: php53-mysql
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libedit.x86_64 0:3.0-2.20090923cvs.el5.art set to be updated
---> Package php-gd.x86_64 0:5.4.28-34.el5.art set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libt1.so.5()(64bit) for package: php-gd
---> Package php-imap.x86_64 0:5.4.28-34.el5.art set to be updated
---> Package php-mbstring.x86_64 0:5.4.28-34.el5.art set to be updated
---> Package php-mysql.x86_64 0:5.4.28-34.el5.art set to be updated
---> Package php-pdo.x86_64 0:5.4.28-34.el5.art set to be updated
---> Package php-xml.x86_64 0:5.4.28-34.el5.art set to be updated
--> Running transaction check
---> Package t1lib.x86_64 0:5.1.2-2.el5.art set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libXaw.so.7()(64bit) for package: t1lib
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
t1lib-5.1.2-2.el5.art.x86_64 from atomic has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: libXaw.so.7()(64bit) is needed by package t1lib-5.1.2-2.el5.art.x86_64 (atomic)
Error: Missing Dependency: libXaw.so.7()(64bit) is needed by package t1lib-5.1.2-2.el5.art.x86_64 (atomic)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: package-cleanup --problems
                        package-cleanup --dupes
                        rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
The program package-cleanup is found in the yum-utils package.
```

**Update**

Attempted to install libxml repo x86_64, however there is a conflict with an i386?!

**rpm -Uhv ftp://xmlsoft.org/libxml2/libxml2-2.7.2-1.x86_64.rpm**

```
Retrieving ftp://xmlsoft.org/libxml2/libxml2-2.7.2-1.x86_64.rpm
warning: /var/tmp/rpm-xfer.pqHChZ: Header V4 DSA signature: NOKEY, key ID de95bc1f
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
        file /usr/share/man/man1/xmlcatalog.1.gz from install of libxml2-2.7.2-1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libxml2-2.6.26-2.1.21.el5_9.3.i386
        file /usr/share/man/man1/xmllint.1.gz from install of libxml2-2.7.2-1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libxml2-2.6.26-2.1.21.el5_9.3.i386
```

**Update 2**

After spending the day pulling my hair out, I rebuilt the VPS and viola. Everything I tried to accomplish has worked. I suspect there was an error with the original build.

Answer (score 1):

in the error message

> Error: Missing Dependency: libXaw.so.7()(64bit) is needed by package t1lib-5.1.2-2.el5.art.x86_64 (atomic`

i think you should check ,do you have install **libXaw** package? or you can `yum install libXaw`.
Hope it can help you out

Comment: Hi, I went to install libXaw2, but a i386 version already appears to be installed. I have amended my post to reflect this.

Comment: just `yum remove libXaw.i686`.But as the *Update* that you post,why i see the **libxml2** package ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `--skip-broken` to work around the problem.

You could try running:

```
package-cleanup --problems
package-cleanup --dupes
rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

The program package-cleanup is found in the `yum-utils` package.